# Additivity over domains in General Measure Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, $g$ and $h$ are nonnegative measurable functions on $X$, $X_o$ a measurable subset of $X$. Then
>   (1) If $g\leq h$ almost everywhere on $X$, then $\int_X g d\mu \leq \int_X hd\mu$; 
>   (2) $\int_X gd\mu =\int_{X_o}gd\mu$   if $\mu(X\backslash X_o)=0$.

I would like to use (1) to prove (2). I really don't have the idea how to start on this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $\mu(X\backslash X_0)=0$, then $g\le \mathbf{1}_{X_0}\cdot g\le g$ almost everywhere on $X$, where $\mathbf{1}_{X_0}$ is the indicator function on $X_0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\int_{X_0}g\,d\mu=\int_X(g\cdot\mathbf{1}_{X_0})\,d\mu$$
Under what conditions is it true that $g\leq g\cdot\mathbf{1}_{X_0}$ almost everywhere?